# Producer Consumer using semaphores and mutexes in Python

Tags: python, mutex, semaphore, python-multithreading, producer-consumer

I'm trying to understand how to implement a Queue with a bounded buffer size that can be used by multiple producers and consumers using Python Semaphores. Here's my implementation:

```
class Q:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.buff = [None]*size
        self.end = 0
        self.start = 0
        self.size = size
        self.end_lock = Lock()  # protect end from race across multiple producers
        self.start_lock = Lock()  # protect start from race across multiple consumers
        self.open = Semaphore(size)  # block till there's space to produce
        self.closed = Semaphore(size) # block till there's item to consume
        for _ in range(size):  # initialize with all closed acquired so that consumer is blocked
            self.closed.acquire()

    def put(self, val):
        self.open.acquire()
        with self.end_lock:
            self.buff[self.end] = val
            self.end = (self.end+1)%self.size
        self.closed.release()

    def get(self):
        self.closed.acquire()
        with self.start_lock:
            val = self.buff[(self.start)%self.size]
            self.start = (self.start+1)%self.size
        self.open.release()
        return val
```

Is this implementation bug-free? Could this be simplified further to use fewer mutexes/semaphores?

Comment: There's a bug in `put`: You write values to indices 1, 2, 3, ... but read them from indices 0, 1, 2, ... So the first `get` will always return `None`.

Comment: And you probably want to use `self.start_lock.release()` instead of `acquire` at the end of `get`. I would consider using the locks as context managers, i.e. `with self.start_lock:`, to avoid this kind of bug.

Comment: Thanks @PoByBolek, I've fixed those issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me. The semaphores prevent concurrent producers and consumers from writing and reading too much and the locks prevent concurrent producers or consumers from modifying the `end` or `start` indices simultaneously.

The two semaphores are definitely necessary. You could remove one of the locks and use it in both `get` and `put` to protect both the `start` and the `end` index which wouldn't allow consumers and producers to access the queue simultaneously. ([CPython's queue implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/queue.py#L121) does this.)

---

I would remove the `size` attribute in favor of `len(self.buff)` though and rename the `start` and `end` indices to `read_index` and `write_index` respectively (and the locks as well). Also, I think you could access the buffer without holding the locks (because [lists themselves are thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319207/are-lists-thread-safe)):

```py
    def put(self, val):
        self.open.acquire()
        with self.write_lock:
            index = self.write_index
            self.write_index = (self.write_index + 1) % len(self.buff)
        self.buff[index] = val
        self.closed.release()

    def get(self):
        self.closed.acquire()
        with self.read_lock:
            index = self.read_index
            self.read_index = (self.read_index + 1) % len(self.buff)
        val = self.buff[index]
        self.open.release()
        return val
```

---

Here's a small test program I used to play around:

```py
def producer(queue, start, end, step):
    for value in range(start, end, step):
        queue.put(value)
    print('Producer finished')


def consumer(queue, count, result, lock):
    local_result = []
    for _ in range(count):
        local_result.append(queue.get())
    with lock:
        result.update(local_result)
    print('Consumer finished')


def main():
    value_count = 500000
    producer_count = 50
    consumer_count = 50
    assert value_count % producer_count == 0
    assert value_count % consumer_count == 0

    queue = Queue(123)
    result = set()
    lock = Lock()
    producers = [Thread(target=producer, args=(queue, i, value_count, producer_count)) for i in range(producer_count)]
    consumers = [Thread(target=consumer, args=(queue, value_count // consumer_count, result, lock)) for _ in range(consumer_count)]

    for p in producers:
        p.start()
    for c in consumers:
        c.start()

    for p in producers:
        p.join()
    for c in consumers:
        c.join()

    if len(result) != value_count:
        raise ValueError('Result size is %d instead of %d' % (len(result), value_count))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from threading import Thread, Semaphore

s = Semaphore(1)

producer_idx = 0
consumer_idx = 0
counter = 0

buf_size = 10
buf = [" "] * buf_size
print(buf)

def produce():
    global producer_idx, counter, buf, buf_size
    while True:
        #s.acquire()
        with s:
            if (counter == buf_size): # full
                #s.release()
                continue
            buf[producer_idx] = "x"
            producer_idx = (producer_idx + 1) % buf_size
            print("{} <= produced 'x' at index='{}'".format(buf, producer_idx))
            counter = counter + 1
        #s.release()
        sleep(1)

def consume():
    global consumer_idx, counter, buf, buf_size
    while True:
        #s.acquire()
        with s:
            if (counter == 0): # empty (next element is)
                #s.release()
                continue
            buf[consumer_idx] = " "
            consumer_idx = (consumer_idx + 1) % buf_size
            print("{} => consumed '{}' at index='{}'".format(buf, buf[consumer_idx], consumer_idx))
            counter = counter - 1
        #s.release()
        sleep(1)

producers = list()

for i in range(randint(10,20)):
    producer = Thread(target=produce)
    producer.start()
    producers.append(producer)

consumers = list()

for i in range(randint(10,20)):
    consumer = Thread(target=consume)
    consumer.start()
    consumers.append(consumer)
```

```
moi python $ python boundedbuffer_semaphore.py 
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='1'
['x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='2'
['x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='3'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='4'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='5'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='6'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='7'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='8'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] <= produced 'x' at index='9'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='0'
[' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='1'
[' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='2'
['x', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='1'
['x', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='3'
['x', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='4'
['x', 'x', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='2'
['x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='3'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='4'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='5'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='6'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='5'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='7'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='6'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='7'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='8'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', ' ', 'x'] => consumed 'x' at index='9'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' ', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='8'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'] <= produced 'x' at index='9'
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='0'
[' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='1'
[' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='2'
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='3'
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='4'
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='5'
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='6'
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='7'
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'x', ' '] => consumed 'x' at index='8'
```

https://github.com/binarytrails/various/blob/master/python/boundedbuffer_semaphore.py